# Leaflet l.layergroup not displaying second layer (features)

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to make a map of the Rockies that has multiple layers with different geological features. The first layer, with hot springs, works perfectly well--each spring has a corresponding marker and pop-up that displays the spring's name and state.

The problem comes when I try to add a second layer with a different geological feature (canyons and gorges). I have used the code from the "hot springs" layer, but it isn't getting added to the map, even when I select it from the layer control.

I don't think the problem is the geoJSON file. (The points will display properly on the map when I look at the file where it is stored on GitHub, which is the canyonsURL.)

Here is the code for the part that isn't working:

```
var canyons = new L.LayerGroup();
d3.json(canyonsURL, function(data) {
    createFeatures2(data.features);
});

function createFeatures2(canyonsURL) {
    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Canyon +
            "<hr><p>" + feature.properties.State);
    }

    function style(feature, layer) {
        return {
            opacity: 0.5,
            radius: 5,
            weight: 1,
            color: "black",
            fillColor: "yellow",
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        }
    }


    var canyon = d3.json(canyonsURL, {
        pointToLayer: function(_geometry, coordinates) {
            return L.circleMarker(coordinates);
        },
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
        style: style
    }).addTo(canyons);
    createMap(canyons)

}
```

I have tried both with and without the final createMap(canyons). I have tried using identical names for functions (instead of adding the 2) to the end.

I'm sure it's right in front of my eyes and I just can't see it. The same code (obviously pointing to a different URL and with slightly different styling) is working fine for the hot springs. What did I mess up on?

EDIT: This is going to get long; sorry. Here is the createMap function:

```
function createMap() {

    var satellite = L.tileLayer("https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}", {
        attribution: "Map data &copy; <a href=\"https://www.openelevationmap.org/\">Openelevationmap</a> contributors, <a href=\"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href=\"https://www.mapbox.com/\">Mapbox</a>",
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: "mapbox.satellite",
        accessToken: API_KEY
    });

    var pirates = L.tileLayer("https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}", {
        attribution: "Map data &copy; <a href=\"https://www.openelevationmap.org/\">Openelevationmap</a> contributors, <a href=\"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href=\"https://www.mapbox.com/\">Mapbox</a>",
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: "mapbox.pirates",
        accessToken: API_KEY
    });

    var terrain = L.tileLayer("https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}", {
        attribution: "Map data &copy; <a href=\"https://www.openelevationmap.org/\">Openelevationmap</a> contributors, <a href=\"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href=\"https://www.mapbox.com/\">Mapbox</a>",
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: "mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2",
        accessToken: API_KEY
    });

    var terrain_rgb = L.tileLayer("https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.terrain-rgb/{z}/{x}/{y}.pngraw?access_token={accessToken}", {
        attribution: "Map data &copy; <a href=\"https://www.openelevationmap.org/\">Openelevationmap</a> contributors, <a href=\"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href=\"https://www.mapbox.com/\">Mapbox</a>",
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: "mapbox.mapbox-terrain-rgb",
        accessToken: API_KEY
    });

    // Define a baseMaps object to hold our base layers
    var baseMaps = {
        // "Elevation Map": elevationmap,
        "Satellite": satellite,
        "Terrain": terrain,
        "Treasure": pirates,
        "Shadow": terrain_rgb
    };

    // Create overlay object to hold our overlay layer
    var overlayMaps = {
        "Hot Springs": springs,
        "Canyons": canyons
    };

    // Create our map, giving it the satellite and hotSprings layers to display on load
    var myMap = L.map("map", {
        center: [
            44.2643, -109.7879
        ],
        zoom: 5,
        layers: [satellite, springs]
    });


    // Create a layer control
    // Pass in our baseMaps and overlayMaps
    // Add the layer control to the map
    L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {
        collapsed: true,
        position: 'bottomright'
    }).addTo(myMap);


}
```

Here is the code that I used to (successfully) add the hot springs:

```
// Create layers for layergroup

var springs = new L.LayerGroup();

d3.json(springsURL, function(data) {
    // Once we get a response, send the data.features object to the createFeatures function
    createFeatures(data.features);
});

function createFeatures(springsURL) {
    // Define a function we want to run once for each feature in the features array
    // Give each feature a popup with name and state of spring
    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.SpringName +
            "<hr><p>" + feature.properties.State);
    }

    function style(feature, layer) {
        return {
            opacity: 0.5,
            radius: 5,
            weight: 1,
            color: "black",
            fillColor: "red",
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        }
    }


    var hotSprings = L.geoJSON(springsURL, {
        pointToLayer: function(_geometry, coordinates) {
            return L.circleMarker(coordinates);
        },
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
        style: style
    }).addTo(springs);

    // Sending our hotSprings layer to the createMap function
    createMap(springs);
}
```

Comment: pls add the function createMap()

Comment: Also add the function to add the hot springs

Comment: Thank you for the reminder! I was worried that it would get too long. I have added both parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function `createMap(springs);` makes no sense. If you add a parameter to the function then you have to read it out. `function createMap() { ... }` it should be `function createMap(layer) { ... }`. But that is not necessary for you.

your script should look like this:

```
var myMap; //the var should init global so you can call it from everywhere
var springs = L.featureGroup(); //Same as L.layerGroup() but with more options.
var canyons = L.featureGroup();



function createMap(){
//...
 myMap = L.map("map", { //<-- without "var"
        center: [
            44.2643, -109.7879
        ],
        zoom: 5,
        layers: [satellite, springs, canyons] //<--- Add canyons
    });
//...
}
createMap();



var style1 = function style(feature) {
        return {
            opacity: 0.5,
            radius: 5,
            weight: 1,
            color: "black",
            fillColor: "red",
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        }
    }

var style2 = function style(feature) {
        return {
            opacity: 0.5,
            radius: 5,
            weight: 1,
            color: "yellow",
            fillColor: "red",
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        }
    }

function createFeatures(springsURL,stlyecallback, layer) {
    // Define a function we want to run once for each feature in the features array
    // Give each feature a popup with name and state of spring
    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.SpringName +
            "<hr><p>" + feature.properties.State);
    }

    var hotSprings = L.geoJSON(springsURL, {
        pointToLayer: function(_geometry, coordinates) {
            return L.circleMarker(coordinates);
        },
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
        style: stlyecallback
    }).addTo(layer);
}


d3.json(springsURL, function(data) {
    createFeatures(data.features, style1, springs);
});


d3.json(springsURL, function(data) {
    createFeatures(data.features, style2, canyons);
});
```

I hope I have no typo...

Comment: You're brilliant! If I want to add additional features, is it the same thing? (Just adding another variable for style and another url for my next geoJSON?) This map is going to be amazing.

Comment: Yes it is so easy ;)